# How can I xpath target text() "only" directly under a html tag, instead of the text contained under "other html child tags"

Tags: xpath

How can I xpath target text() "only" directly under a html tag, instead of the text contained under "other html child tags"

Consider

```
<li class="one">
<label class="two">
    <span class="two-one">Unwanted text</span>
    Wanted text only directly under under label (not under span)
</label>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options :

If you have multiple lines to fetch :

```
//label/text()[normalize-space()]
```

If you have just one line to fetch, use position. For your sample data:

```
//label/text()[last()]
```

[last()] could be replaced with [1],[2],[3],... to specify the position of the text you're trying to get.